# Icon and Text Vertical alignment css

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="container-fluid" >
    <section id="current-weather">
        <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3 " style="width: 60%;">
            <div class="card-header">
                weather
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2>{{location}}</h2>
                <hr style="width: 30%;height: 2px; margin: 20px auto 20px auto;color: black;">
                <h5 class="card-title"><i class="wi wi-owm-{{weather_current['weather'][0]['id']}}" style="font-size: 2.2em;"></i>{{weather_current['temp']}}°C</h5>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

I have a problem with alignment text and icon. [Look at screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGQiq.png)
I've already tried to use vertical-align: middle and baseline. Maybe somebody can resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate your work, but I was asking to align icon and text in one line not the whole container on web page.

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k6a0.png)

Finally I coped with that. Here is my solution:

```css
.align-inline {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" >
    <section id="current-weather">
        <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                weather
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2>{{location}}</h2>
                <hr style="width: 30%;height: 2px; margin: 20px auto 20px auto;color: black;">
                <h5 class="card-title align-inline"><i class="wi wi-owm-{{weather_current['weather'][0]['id']}}" style="font-size: 2.2em;"></i>{{weather_current['temp']}}°C</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

[This is how result looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDuBu.png)

Comment: Ah I'm sorry my bad. I misunderstand the question because I was unable to figure out what you exactly said by watching the things that you have written earlier. Anyway, nice to hear that the problem is now solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I have aligned it vertically and horizontally.

```css
.container-fluid{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" >
    <section id="current-weather">
        <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                weather
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2>{{location}}</h2>
                <hr style="width: 30%;height: 2px; margin: 20px auto 20px auto;color: black;">
                <h5 class="card-title"><i class="wi wi-owm-{{weather_current['weather'][0]['id']}}" style="font-size: 2.2em;"></i>{{weather_current['temp']}}°C</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Thanks and best regards!